# How to create a 'tee' command in Ruby for a Unix like pipeline?

Tags: ruby, io

I came across the question about [creating memory-efficient Ruby pipe class with lazy evaluation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999888/how-to-create-a-memory-efficient-ruby-pipe-class-with-lazy-evaluation/20051293#comment37233276_20051293) Some code is given to effectively create a pipeline of commands using lazy enumerators. I have been messing round with it and have implemented a `tee` command shown below. I feel like there is a better way to do it though.

```
class Pipe

  class Tee

    def initialize(pipe)
      @pipe = pipe
      @buffer = []
      @pipe.source = self.to_enum
    end

    def <<(item)
      @buffer << item
      # puts "Added '#{item}' to buffer: #{@buffer.inspect}"
    end

    def to_enum
      Enumerator.new do |yielder|
        item = @buffer.shift
        yielder << item if item
      end.lazy
    end

  end

  attr_writer :source

  def initialize
    @commands = []
    @source = nil
  end

  def add(command, opts = {})
    @commands << [command, opts]
    self
  end

  def run
    enum = @source

    @commands.each do |command, options|
      enum = method(command).call(enum, options)
    end

    enum.each {}

    enum
  end

  def cat(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.map { |line| yielder << line } if enum

      options[:input].tap do |ios|
        ios.each { |line| yielder << line }
      end
    end.lazy
  end

  def out(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        puts line
        yielder << line
      end
    end.lazy
  end

  def cut(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        fields = line.chomp.split(%r{#{options[:delimiter]}})

        yielder << fields[options[:field]]
      end
    end.lazy
  end

  def upcase(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        yielder << line.upcase
      end
    end
  end

  def tee(enum, options)

    teed = Tee.new(options.fetch(:other))
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        yielder << line
        teed << line
      end
    end
  end

  def grep(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        yielder << line if line.match(options[:pattern])
      end
    end.lazy
  end

end

another_pipe = Pipe.new
another_pipe.add(:grep, pattern: /testing/i)
another_pipe.add(:out)

pipe = Pipe.new
pipe.add(:cat, :input => StringIO.new("testing\na new\nline"))
# pipe.add(:grep, pattern: /line/)
pipe.add(:tee, :other => another_pipe)
pipe.add(:upcase)
pipe.add(:out)
pipe.run

puts "================================================="
another_pipe.run
```

Here's the output:

> ```
> TESTING
> A NEW
> LINE
> =================================================
> testing
> ```

Does anyone see a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't call `Enumerator#lazy` in the `pipe` or `tee` methods when you do in all of the others?

Comment: @Jordan I think I left it out by mistake. They should probably both use Enumerator#lazy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but it's an interesting one.

First, a couple small things:

1. In `Pipe#run`:

   ```
   enum = method(command).call(enum, options)
   ```

   Calling `method` has a lot of overhead, and `send(command, enum, options)` does the same thing.
2. Also in `Pipe#run`:

   ```
   enum.each {}
   ```

   The purpose of this is to cause the final object to be enumerated. We can do the same thing cheaper (even an empty block takes CPU cycles) with `enum.to_a`, which is also aliased as `enum.force`.

Those things aside, the first thing I noticed is that there's a lot of repetition. `grep` and `upcase`, for example, only differ on one line. We can extract the shared code out into another method, which I'll call `enum_lazy`:

```
def upcase(enum, options)
  enum_lazy(enum) do |line, yielder|
    yielder << line.upcase
  end
end

def grep(enum, options)
  enum_lazy(enum) do |line, yielder|
    yielder << line if line.match(options[:pattern])
  end
end

private
def enum_lazy(enum, &block)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    enum.each do |line|
      yield(line, yielder)
    end
  end.lazy
end
```

...but this made me realize that some of these methods don't need the `yielder` pattern at all. For example, `upcase` takes one element at a time, performs an operation on it, and yields one value each time—it's just a lazy map, and this is equivalent:

```
def upcase(enum, options)
  enum.lazy.map(&:upcase)
end
```

Since we called `lazy`, this will return an Enumerator::Lazy as expected. We can simplify `cut` and `out` in the same way:

```
def out(enum, options)
  enum.lazy.map do |line|
    puts line
    line
  end
end

def cut(enum, options)
  enum.lazy.map do |line|
    fields = line.chomp.split(options[:delimiter])
    fields[ options[:field] ]
  end
end
```

`grep` is different, because we only don't want output for every input line. As it turns out, though, `grep` is just a lazy `select`:

```
def grep(enum, options)
  enum.lazy.select {|line| line =~ options[:pattern] }
end
```

That just leaves `cat`. I have a strong inkling that there's a similar optimization we could do for `cat`, but I haven't yet been able to actually figure it out. Perhaps someone else can help figure it out.

Here's the final code:

```
class Pipe
  class Tee
    # (no changes here)
  end

  attr_writer :source

  def initialize
    @commands = []
    @source = nil
  end

  def add(command, opts = {})
    @commands << [command, opts]
    self
  end

  def run
    enum = @source

    @commands.each do |command, options|
      enum = send(command, enum, options)
    end

    enum.force
    enum
  end

  def cat(enum, options)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.map { |line| yielder << line } if enum

      options[:input].tap do |ios|
        ios.each { |line| yielder << line }
      end
    end.lazy
  end

  def out(enum, options)
    enum.lazy.map do |line|
      puts line
      line
    end
  end

  def cut(enum, options)
    enum.lazy.map do |line|
      fields = line.chomp.split(/#{options[:delimiter]}/)
      fields[ options[:field] ]
    end
  end

  def upcase(enum, options)
    enum.lazy.map(&:upcase)
  end

  def tee(enum, options)
    teed = Tee.new(options.fetch(:other))

    enum_lazy(enum) do |line, yielder|
      yielder << line
      teed << line
    end
  end

  def grep(enum, options)
    enum.lazy.select {|line| line =~ options[:pattern] }
  end

  private
  def enum_lazy(enum, &block)
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      enum.each do |line|
        yield(line, yielder)
      end
    end.lazy
  end
end
```

Comment: Since I just remembered that your real question was whether or not your Tee class could be improved... somewhat anti-climactically, I can't think of any obvious improvements. Good work. :)